# How can i lower the zuul-proxy delay?

Tags: spring, netflix-eureka, netflix-zuul

I have an `eureka-server`, `eureka-client-1`, `eureka-client-2` and `zuul-proxy` deployed.

The `eureka-client-*` are changing from `{status:"UP"}` to `{status:"DOWN"}`.

How can I lower the delay so that `zuul-proxy` always points to one of the `eureka-client-*` that is `{status:"UP"}`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are several options to reduce the delay.
The values in below are just for example.

**Eureka Server Response Cache**

*eureka server property*

```
eureka.server.response-cache-update-interval-ms: 5000 (default 30000)
```

Eureka server has response cache for the performance, so it doesn't return actual values that it knows during above milliseconds. You can reduce this delay with above property.

**Zuul Ribbon Cache**

*zuul property*

```
ribbon.ServerListRefreshInterval: 5000  (default 30000)
```

As you know, zuul is using Ribbon for load-balancing and Ribbon has cache for server list. The default value is 30 seconds. You can adjust this value with above property to reduce ribbon cache time.

**Eureka Client Cache**

*eureka client property (In your case, it's zuul property)*

```
eureka.client.registryFetchIntervalSeconds : 30
```

Zuul is another eureka client and it is using eureka client to retrieve available server list for a specific service. The default interval for this is 30 seconds and you can adjust this value with the above property.

#### Lease Expiration Duration

eureka instance properties (In your case, for your `eureka-client-1`, `eureka-client-2`)

```
eureka.instance.lease-expiration-duration-in-seconds: 60 (default 90)
```

If Eureka server didn't receive heartbeat during above seconds, eureka server removes that instance from available server list. Each your client sends a heartbeat in every 30 seconds (that value is also configurable, but don't change this property because eureka server has some codes based on the assumption of this 30 seconds). So 90 seconds means that eureka instance will be removed from the list if it fails to send (or server fails to receive) heartbeats at three consecutive times. You can reduce this duration, but you may have some risks of that. This property must exist on your eureka client side.

There is a great article about this information here : http://blog.abhijitsarkar.org/technical/netflix-eureka/